# Bigquery extract nested JSON using UNNEST

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table in Bigquery which has JSON data like below.

```
{
    "block_id": "000000000000053d90510fa4bbfbbed243baca490c85ac7856b1a1fab4d367e4",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "transaction_id": "4529b00ed3315ff85408118ef5992b3ad2b47f4c1c088cc3dea46084bdb600df",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "input_script_bytes": "BIvbBRoDwAgBEi9QMlNIL0JJUDE2L3NsdXNoL1Is+r5tbf4lsR1tDNnUOZk9JGzN4MkWc914Rol/+47Hn+msUG/nAQAAAAAAAAA=",
            "input_pubkey_base58_error": null
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "output_satoshis": "5048296000",
            "output_pubkey_base58_error": "Cannot cast this script to a pay-to-address type"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": "838b03a6f741c844e22079cdb0d1401b9687d65a82f355ccb0a993b042c49d54",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "input_script_bytes": "RzBEAiAE5fM2NHAEaWy9utrC2ypHQsKwUDeUTp/gjbj5tSy3lwIgUXXFcuwXhr3tx1m5D+kznhklTAK9+YYHRcB43aXTAZ8BQQR86qInfhczeYqqJsAD9yFfxSAzBAmIBlxk/bpTQSxgLkF4Ttipiuuoxt6TTVMDK/eewwFhAPJiHrvZq0psKI1d",
            "input_pubkey_base58_error": null
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "output_satoshis": "1",
            "output_pubkey_base58_error": null
          },
          {
            "output_satoshis": "4949999",
            "output_script_bytes": "dqkU4E0i4TQg1I6OpprIt6v7Ipuda/GIrA==",
            "output_pubkey_base58_error": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract the `transaction_id`,`output.input_pubkey_base58_error` from this table.

How can achieve this by using UNNEST? 
You can refer the above example code.

Comment: is it one field that consists of JSON string?

Comment: Yes its JSON,you can see that from the above JSON contents.

Comment: my question meant to be - is it just one field? or representation of table's schema? users who asking this type of questions frequently use it for schema representation so that is please clarify!

Comment: Yeah the above json has 2 fields only. It has many columns. Its an open dataset from google. `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.blocks` You can refer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would like to clarify that you said you are interested in the fields `transaction_id` and `output.input_pubkey_base58_error`, but the latter does not exist according to the table schema (maybe you were referring to `inputs.input_pubkey_base58_error` or `outputs.output_pubkey_base58_error`). So I believe it is worth that you clarify your scenario and/or use case.

In any case, working with [the public Bitcoin dataset](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bitcoin-in-bigquery-blockchain-analytics-on-public-data) you mentioned, you can use a query like the one below in order to query (using Standard SQL) only for the fields you are interested in.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  tr.transaction_id,
  inp.input_pubkey_base58_error,
  out.output_pubkey_base58_error
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.blocks`,
  UNNEST(transactions) AS tr,
  UNNEST(tr.inputs) AS inp,
  UNNEST(tr.outputs) as out
LIMIT
  100
```

In this query, I am making use of the [`UNNEST` StandardSQL operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) in order to query for specific fields inside an array, but I strongly recommend you to go through the documentation in order to see more details and specific examples on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the sintax should be like this. (Didn't try it!). Guessing that your table is called mybitcoindata in bigquery

```
SELECT block_id, output.output_pubkey_base58_error
FROM yourdataset.yourtable as A
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(A.transactions) AS transaction
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(transaction.outputs) AS output
;
```

There are very good examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)

EDIT:
Just tested. If you convert your json data to single line json, you can create the table in bigquery. The above query works to explode multiple arrays.