# How to extract the first key value pair in a JSON object with BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am trying to extract values of a certain key in a JSON object with BigQuery. However, the key is unique for each record in the table as shown in the picture.
[Keys and values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAgzL.png)

My JSON Object is structured like this: [Object's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVRYP.png)

(Note: I am trying to unnest regularHours array that is the value of this unique key.)

I tried using - "SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(response.data, '$.menus') FROM MyDataSet.UberEats"
This only gives me the key and its values but I'm only after unnesting the array value of this key and I don't know how to proceed further. (Note: response is the field name)

Comment: Please attach image directly.

Comment: Hi, since this is my first question, I am not allowed to post an image directly on the post. I need 10 reputation and I am new to stack overflow. so yeah :(

Comment: Regardless of your reputation level, you should almost never use images. Always add information as editable text so that it is copiable by someone wanting to try out a solution

Comment: Sure, thanks for the info. I am new to StackOverflow, next time I'll follow this!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following UDF to convert the Dictionary object, as we cannot refer to the Dynamic keys in the Statically typed SQL statement

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION dictToArray(input JSON)
RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.entries(input).map(([id, values]) => ({ id, values }));
""";

-- Direct Function
SELECT
  dictToArray(response)
FROM (SELECT JSON '{ "ID1": [10,11,12,13], "ID2": [20,21,22,23,24], "ID3": [31,32,33,34] }' AS response

Output
------
[{"id":"ID1","values":[10,11,12,13]},{"id":"ID2","values":[20,21,22,23,24]},{"id":"ID3","values":[31,32,33,34]}]

--Unnest Operation with Bigquery Native Types
SELECT
    SAFE.STRING(item.id) AS id,
    SAFE.INT64(value) AS values
FROM (SELECT JSON '{ "ID1": [10,11,12,13], "ID2": [20,21,22,23,24], "ID3": [31,32,33,34] }' AS response)
     LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(dictToArray(response), '$')) AS item
     LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(item.values)) AS value

/*----+--------*
| id  | values |
+-----+--------|
| ID1 | 10     |    
| ID1 | 11     |
| ID1 | 12     |
| ID1 | 13     |
| ID2 | 20     |
| ID2 | 21     |
| ID2 | 22     |
| ID2 | 23     |
| ID2 | 24     |
| ID3 | 31     |
| ID3 | 32     |
| ID3 | 33     |
| ID3 | 34     |
+-----+-------*/
```

Comment: Check this out as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216389/bigquery-extract-nested-json-with-dynamic-keys-and-values